# Integrating $\iiint_{E} (10xz+3) \; dV$, where $E$ is the portion of the unit ball above the $xy$-plane

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the triple integral
\begin{equation*}
\iiint_{E} (10xz+3) \; dV,
\end{equation*}
where $E$ is the portion of the unit ball above the $xy$-plane i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
E = \left\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1, \; \; z\geq 0\right\}.
\end{equation*}
I think that I have to transfer coordinates. Something like polar coordinates, but I cannot seem to get a good transformation.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can do it in standard coordinates too. The limits of integration will be ugly but the integrand is easy to deal with.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out (even by recalling basic geometry formulas) what the volume of $E$ is. So, $\int_E 3 \, dV$ should be easy to calculate. Also, the 10 infront of $xz$ can be "pulled out" of the integral. So, really the only thing is to calulcate $\int_E xz \, dV$. Do you know the change of variables formula and how to use spherical polar coordinates as substitution? If yes, this is an easy computation in the sense that there's nothing tricky going on (just remember to multiply by the determinant of the Jacobian)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even really need to do a transformation for this one! Just notice that
$$\iiint_E 10xz\ dV = 0$$
because $E$ is symmetric in the $x$ coordinate and $10xz$ is an odd function of $x$. Then, the integral reduces to
$$\iiint_E 3\ dV$$
Which is just $3/2$ times the volume of the unit ball.

Comment: very nice! I initially only saw that $E$ was not symmetric in the $z$-coordinate, so I abandoned the symmetry approach... but of course I should have noticed $E$ is symmetric in $x$. Also, it would be a good exercise for the OP to rigorously prove (the intuitively obvious statement) that the symmetry in $E$ wrt $x$ and oddness of the integrand wrt $x$ imply that the integral is $0$.